# DOM exception 18 in PhantomJS when trying to get the page title

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I have this error:

[image]

When I try to execute this code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph) {
    return ph.createPage(function(page) {
        return page.open("file:///C:/Users/amouna/editor.html", function(status) {
            console.log("opened google? ", status);
            return page.evaluate((function() {
                window.addEventListener('load',Loaded,false);
                function Loaded(){
                    // return document.title;
                    return  document.getElementById('GraphImage');
                }
            }), function(result) {
                console.log('Page title is ' + result);
                return ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
}, {
    dnodeOpts: {weak: false}
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you can also post the error here instead of only referring to a link? As soon as the link is broken, we won't be able to see the error anymore.

Comment: Your code isn't doing anything useful, because you're not returning anything from `page.evaluate`, so `result` will be null. Since `page.open` waits for the page load, it shouldn't be necessary to use `window.addEventListener('load',Loaded,false);` at all. Perhaps try `page.evaluate(function() { return document.title; }, function(result){...});`. As for your error, this code shouldn't produce this error, so it comes probably from the page itself. See...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phantomjs throwing DOM exception 18 on canvas.toDataURL using src images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424765/phantomjs-throwing-dom-exception-18-on-canvas-todataurl-using-src-images)